# VB Macro to upload Test Cases to ALM

Tags: excel, vba, alm

I am working on a macro to upload the test cases from excel to ALM using VBA scripting. 
I got connected to the ALM using the below code:

```
Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
Dim sUserName, sPassword
sUserName = "user name" '-- change me
sPassword = "" '-- change me
QCConnection.InitConnectionEx "ALM bin link" '-- change me
QCConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword
```

but unable to proceed further. please help me out. Now I know we have an Excel Add In for this but I wanted to do it via my own macro. I have multiple sheets with N number of test cases each. I am aiming a macro that will upload Test Cases from all the Sheets at once.

My Column Structure in Excel looks something like this

[image: Column Snapshot from My Excel]

Answer (score 1):

You can create one configuration sheet within same excel where you writing macro code. In configuration you can create columns with details like Source sheet, Destination, Cell Range to Copy etc. Loop your macro thorough this configuration sheet and while looping perform copy paste based on configuration.

Comment: Could you Kindly explain in more detail. I am new to VBA

Comment: Open new excel file, add one new sheet and in that sheet create columns

Comment: 1) Source Sheet ( this column should contain name or sheet from your test cases workbook).                         2) Destination ( this column should contain Destination where you want to past this data          3) Cell Range ( this colulmn should contain the Cells from sheet mentioned in first column).

Comment: Now in your macro refer to the above sheet and start loop from your second row as in first row you would have mentioned column names. So from second row first cell contains your sheet name. So read this sheet from your test cases for mentioned cell range in third column. And paste same at destination mentioned in second column.

Comment: So suppose you have five sheets in your test case workbook, then in configuration you will have 5 rows with details of sheet name, cell range etc.